# web service in java related problem

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services

i  want to bulid an web service application using java. main theme is i want to create a student database and users of the system will view a particular students information based on their authentication. for example an student can view his detail information but can't view detail info of another student.

my problem is how i will manage it?  i am a novice for web service and all i know is from some tutorials where a 'Hello World' is printed or a calculator or converter application. there is no use of any database. so how can i build my application? how i will link it up with database?

normally i works in eclipse and microsoft sql server studio. so i am planning to do so for my project.

can anyone please help me. any tutorial, book or any idea regarding this will be helpful for me. please help and tell me what will be the steps for this work.

Comment: is your question about "managing" some aspect of web-services, or, is it about learning web-services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either REST or SOAP as a web service architecture.

I have been using REST and followed [this tutorial](http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/restful-webservices-using-jboss-resteasy-tutorial/).

As long as the question of linking with database is there, once you go through the example, you will know where to insert the DB access code. There will be an annotated java file which will return responses. That is the place where you should query your database.

Anyways, i recommend you go through this tutorial first to get an idea of how it actually works.